# How to understand 'qualification' in 'One qualification concerns constructions in which...'?

Tags: meaning

> This is the one place where the accusative is normally the only
> option: the nominative [b] versions are clearly ungrammatical. **One**
> **qualification** concerns constructions in which the PP stands alone or
> in post-verbal position.

GPT says 'one qualification' has the meaning of 'a special case'. But in most online Dictionaries, there is not a such explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This meaning of the word *qualification* is used to add a limit to a general statement.

For example, in [the Oxford Learner's definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/qualification), the relevant definition is

> ​**3** [countable, uncountable] information that you add to a statement to limit the effect that it has or the way it is applied

In [the Cambridge definition](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/qualification) it's

> qualification noun (LIMIT)
>
> an extra piece of information that limits the effect of something that you say or write

So in your quoted passage, the second sentence places a limit on the first sentence, which is similar to adding a special case.